# iOS 7 UISearchDisplayController not cleaning background when search data

Tags: ios, popup, ios7, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I'm upgrading my Apps to iOS 7. Actually I have a big issue with UISearchDisplayController.

If i display it into a PopUp until I don't start a Search it works fine, but when I insert something into the SearchBar the search works fine, but I see the search result overlapped to the old contents.

In iOS 6 it all works fine. Here is a link to an example project which shows the problem.
[Example project](http://www.htmedia.it/files/TestSearchBar.zip)

Attached to this post there are two images.

Thank you for your help.

[image: Before entering search text]

[image: After entering search text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the cell's background color is clear color, and so is the table view's. You can either implement the search display controller's delegate method `searchDisplayController:didLoadSearchResultsTableView:` and set the background color to what you need (but not `[UIColor clearColor]`). Or change your cells' background color to be an opaque color.